# install git without admin/sudo or make

Tags: git

I have a MacBook Pro without admin or sudo access, but I need git. XCode is not installed, so I don't have access to make, so I cannot build from source. /usr/local is locked down, so I cannot use MacPorts or Homebrew either.

How do I get a working git binary?

Comment: Have a friend with a Mac install the Homebrew version (or compile it), then copy it over.

Answer (score 1):

- Download the Git installer from https://git-scm.com/download/mac
- Open the installer package with [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com)
- Copy the required binaries into `~/bin` and update your `PATH`

Comment: I’ve tried this and it mostly works, except for ‘git stash’ complains that stash is not a git command

Comment: 'stash' is certainly a subcommand for git 2.2, so what command line are you passing and what actual error do you get?  Also, what is the output of 'git --version'?